# Double Expectation of a Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory

If there are two sub-sigma algebras $\mathcal{G}$ and $\mathcal{H}$ of $\mathcal{F}$, neither a subset of the other from a probability space $(Y,\mathcal{F},P)$ and a random variable $X$ which is not measurable with respect to either $\mathcal{G}$ or $\mathcal{H}$, can I apply double expectation on the conditional expectation of $X|\mathcal{G}$ like this:

$$
E[E[X|\mathcal{G}]|\mathcal{H}] = E[X|\mathcal{G}]
$$

Thanks.

Comment: What is $H$ in the property you want? Are $\cal G$ and $\cal H$ _sub_$\sigma$-algebras of $\cal F$?

Comment: Did you mean to condition on $\mathcal{H}$ rather than $\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Yeah my mistake... G and H are sub-algs of F and the conditional is E[E[X|G]|H]... Edited above.  Thanks.

Comment: If this were the case, then by definition of conditional expectation, $E[X\mid \mathcal{G}]$ has to be $\mathcal{H}$-measurable. But we already know that it is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, so if $\mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathcal{H}$ doesn't hold, there is lots of examples where this is not true (see e.g.  Davide's example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property doesn't hold when $\Omega=\{a,b,c\}$, $\cal F:= 2^\Omega$, $\cal G:=\{\emptyset,\{a,b\},\{c\},\Omega\}$, $\cal H:=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c\},\Omega\}$ and $X:=\chi_{\{b\}}$.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was thinking of... Does it not hold because the information from G {a,b} and H {b,c} just ends up being omega?  Is there any way to simplify this when the tower property doesn't apply?

Comment: With the imposed condition, a random variable is measure with respect to both $\cal G$ and $\cal H$ if and only if it's constant.

Comment: And then would the condition also be equal to E[E[X|H]|G]?

Comment: Of which case are you talking about?

Comment: Using the sigma algebras you described since X is not measurable wrt to F or G does the order of the conditioning matter?  Does E[E[X|H]|G] =E[E[X|G]|H]?

Comment: As each term  is $\cal G$ and $\cal H$ measurable, it's constant. Now you have to check whether it's the same value.